# How to profile GNOME desktop start?

Tags: gnome

How can I profile what programs are making use of the HD to load after I type in my login credentials?

It's taking a bit too much time lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried it but it seems [Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) could help you out (it's available in the Software Center).

> Bootchart is a tool for performance analysis and visualization of the GNU/Linux boot process. Resource utilization and process information are collected during the boot process and are later rendered in a PNG, SVG or EPS encoded chart.

I'm not sure if it will also profile after login in though.

Comment: Bootchart *will* profile all the way to an idle desktop; it's how the Ubuntu boot time measurements are made.

Comment: @Oliver Lalonde: He also should install pybootchartgui. Last time I checked, it wasn't installed automatically, but you need it for creating the chart. @RAOF But it will fail if booting is taking too long. In that case you'd adjust the sleep time in the "pre-stop script" section of `/etc/init/bootchart.conf`

Comment: Thanks. I thought it didn't do up to the desktop before, but that's because it seems to have some default stop parameters - running pybootchartgui on it's own made it ignore them.